# How to use the extension modules in saltstack from Git repository?

Tags: salt-stack

I have one extension python module in Git repository, named `compute_pillar.py`.

I want to use this as an external pillar, below are my `extension_module` settings:

```
extension_modules: /var/cache/salt/master/gitfs

gitfs_ssl_verify: False
gitfs_provider: gitpython
gitfs_remotes:
  - git@git.corp.company.com:Saltstack/saltit-automation.git:
    - root: salt
    - base: master
  - file:///var/cache/salt/master/gitfs
```

Below is my `pillar.conf`:

```
ext_pillar:
  - cmd_json: 'echo {\"arg\":\"value\"}'
  - compute_pillar: True
```

Now when calling `pillar.items`, it calls the `cmd_json` as it is local, but for `compute_pillar` it never executes, below is the error message in the log:

> [salt.utils.lazy  ][DEBUG   ][24791] Could not LazyLoad
>   compute_pillar.ext_pillar: 'compute_pillar.ext_pillar' is not
>   available. [salt.pillar      ][CRITICAL][24791] Specified ext_pillar
>   interface compute_pillar is unavailable

What is the configuration setting to call the extension modules directly from git repository?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to point salt to `/var/cache/salt/master/gitfs`.

Assuming your gitfs backend is configured properly and working, create a directory called `_modules` under `salt` directory (for example for roots backend `/srv/salt/_modules`) and put your extension python module here, push to git, wait 60 seconds or run `salt-run fileserver.update`.

Now just sync your minion `salt minion_A saltutil.sync_all` and you should be able to use the module.